# Unity – Resolving objects by passing constructor parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following code:

```
interface IParent
{ }
class Parent1 : IParent
{
  public Parent1 (Document doc)
  {
  }
}
class Parent2 : IParent
{
  public Parent2 (Document doc)
  {
  }
}
```

My unity container is configured as per below:

```
Container.RegisterType<IParent, Parent1>("Parent1");
Container.RegisterType<IParent, Parent2>("Parent2");
```

I'm trying to resolve an IParent object (of type Parent1 or Parent2) by passing in an instance of Document to its constructor:

```
string parent = "Parent1";
IParent parent = Container.Resolve<IParent>(parent, new ParameterOverride("Document", doc));
```

This isn't working for me. Using the debugger to step into the above line I get into the constructor but the Document is empty. i.e. it seems like a new Document(), and not the actual doc that I'm passing in when calling Resolve.

My question is how do I pass in an instance of doc to resolve a concrete type of IParent?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register `Parent1` with dependency to `Document` in constructor:

```
    Container.RegisterType<IParent, Parent1>("Parent1", new InjectionConstructor(doc));
```

then you can resolve an instance of that class:

```
        string parentClass = "Parent1";
        IParent parent = Container.Resolve<IParent>(parentClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the use the name of the parameter declared in constructer and not the actual type, as such:

```
IParent parent = Container.Resolve<IParent>(parent, new ParameterOverride("doc", doc));
```